# How to delete a file from the server using Fog and Carrierwave after it's being downloaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

Im using Carrierwave and Fog to upload a temporary file to S3. I then use `fog_authenticated_url_expiration` to give a expiring url to the use. After the user download this file, I want to remove it from S3. How can I do this?

Comment: read documentation https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#removing-uploaded-files

Comment: Have you thought about having another endpoint to your app where the user can go and be redirected to the S3 url? In the same action you could set a sidekiq worker (or some such) to delete the file in x minutes?